# Add entry to textbox in other class?

Tags: c#, winforms, class

I am having a form in which I can input data from one window and then press enter button (btnEnter) and click display (btnShowBooks) button and show data in other window. When I press btnEnter with code below and then click btnShowBooks to display input in new window the txtBookList textbox is still empty. Here is a simplified code which doesn't work and hope for some tips.

**BookEntry form file**

```
private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BookList bookList = new BookList();
    bookList.txtBookList.Text = "aaa";
}
```

**BookList form file** in which I have the layout and close button so there isn't any relevant code. There is only texbox named txtBookList and btnClose button.

In BookList designer file I have made the field public:

```
public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtBookList;
```

Regards. HelpNeeder.

-- SOLVED --

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;

namespace Lab_8
{
    public partial class BookEntry : Form
    {
        BookList bookList = new BookList();

        public BookEntry()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bookList.txtBookList.Text = "aaa";
        }

        private void btnShowBooks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bookList.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just replicated this and it is working fine (VS2010 .NET4).. are you showing the same instance of the form afterwards? (as below):

```
BookList bookList = new BookList();
bookList.txtBookList.Text = "aaa";
bookList.Show();
```

**EDIT**

Given your response, it seems that you're instantiating separate forms. Here is what you need to do:

First, in your main form, declare this:

```
private BookList _bookList = new BookList();
```

Then, wherever you need to reference that form, use _bookList to accomplish that. E.g:

```
_bookList.txtBookList.Text = "aaa";
_bookList.ShowDialog();
```

You need to keep 1 reference to the dialog whenever you're performing tasks. If you do this each time you want to operate on that form:

```
BookList bookList = new BookList();
```

You are actually creating completely different copies of the form.

Comment: I have ShowDialog in btnShowBooks button.

Comment: I edited my post.. but I see you've just resolved it based on exactly my suggestion in my edit anyway! Happy coding.

Comment: I am not sure if I should be initializing things outside of classes.

Comment: It generally doesn't matter within a WinForms application.. if you feel uncomfortable about it, then you can just declare it as a member of the class, then instantiate it in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new BookList and then losing it as soon as the method returns.  Are you trying to access a BookList object inside your BookEntry form?  It should look more like:

```
private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // bookListForm is the ID of the form in the designer 
    bookListForm.txtBookList.Text="aaa";
}
```

Comment: So you suggesting that I should be entering the items to the textbox in button that displays a new window? It does work.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand your question.  I'm mainly saying that you are creating a BookList object, but never showing it.  You need to Show the form somehow (.Show() being the primary method)  Also, misread the class type (BookList is a Form, not a Control) so Show is needed.  My original design was for a SubControl on the a BookList Control.

Comment: Well, but I do understand you. Please look at my edit. I just had to create a constructor outside of classes. But should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Where are you doing the .Show() on the BookList form.  Make sure you not creating 2 separate instances of the form, and setting the textbox on one but showing the other (this is what I suspect).

Comment: EDIT. I have ShowDialog in btnShowBooks button.